# Develop with react native under debian 9

Tags: react-native

I'd like to know how I can develop using linux (for example debian 9) and use my iPhone to see what I am developing.

I don't want to use macOS to do this and the best would be to see the result under Android and iOS without simulator, directly on phones.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stuck with Linux OS. You can test you app on android variant only (on both emulator or physical device)

In order to test your app on iOS you need to have a mac machine to generate / build the project.

If you don't have a mac system you can go with Expo SDK.

[**Expo**](https://expo.io/) is a free and open source toolchain built around React Native to help you build native iOS and Android projects using JavaScript and React.

You can easily get started [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/introduction/installation/)